# Folder in bin/debug not copying to output directory

Tags: c#, clickonce, xulrunner, geckofx, output-directory

I have developed one `winform` application which using `geckofx22.0` and `xulrunner` . So here i need to copy the `xulrunner` folder to bin . so i did, and the program works cool. But the problem is when i publish this project it does not copy the `xulrunner` folder in output directory and causes the application to crash . `xulrunner` folder contains some `dll` files and `txt` which requires to run and initiate the `geckofx` . Can anyone help in this ? how can i make the clickoneapplication can refer this xulrunner folder ? 
I have initilized the xulrunner folder by following in my project and its worked good.

```
 Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/xulrunner");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy your `xulrunner` folder into project. After set the properties for each files in the project as `Build Action` to `content` and `Copy to Output Direcotry` to `Copy if newer` or `Copy always`. Then build your application . When you publish after these steps your `xulrunner` will be deployed in output directory, so you can execute the ClickOnce application without any error.

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded external packages (DLLS) and used them in your project.
When you add reference to the DLLs, you should set the Copy local = true (unless they are in GAC or some other way)

This make sure when you build your project, all referenced DLLs will be copied to the build output folder.

Does all the dlls and files in your downloaded package are copied ? You need to know, If the builder only copies the referenced DLL, then you might want to publish the project with the DLLs included (or else it will fail in runtime when it will try to use a file that does not exist in folder).

Comment: i have referenced some dll files which are copied to output directory , but i'm not referencing any ddl files in xulrunner and i'm setting the path to that xulrunner folder as mentioned in my program. If you understand my question correctly, you come to know that i just need to copy that folder to the output directory when i'm converting the project to clickonce application .

Comment: How does you project know what is Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize ? Since it is referenced.